# Effective way to avoid caching during Jquery Get (AJAX)

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, caching, jquery

I am experiencing random occurrences of caching of Ajax requests created through Jquery's get.

The Jquery gets are done in the most straight forward conventional way (route + params + callback)

I am already using

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
```

But it doesn't seem to always work. I get how ajaxSetup no cache works, and I see the added random parameter being added to my request url.

My current browser is IE 8.0

Does anyone know of another solution besides the ajaxSetup way...

Comment: how do you know it's caching?

Comment: Your browser won't cache requests for different URLs (which is the purpose of the random parameter).

Comment: I know because I have breakpoints that aren't hit in the controller. The requests come back too quickly too :-)

Comment: Also clearing browser cache makes me hit the breakpoints

Comment: Did you use Fiddler to inspect the requests and make sure the variable for the timestamp is being added to each of the requests (ensuring that the cache:false is working?

Comment: Yes, I debugged it on the server. The weird thing is that it doesn't always cache... The param is there. I will keep debugging it. I just wondered if someone has seen similar behavior in IE 8.

Comment: Debugging it on the server isn't the same as using Fiddler. Fiddler will monitor all HTTP requests and show you EXACTLY what the requests are, what the status code is, etc. It will give you the raw dump including visibility to see what the parameter is. Debugging it on the server only means you have a break point and are only watching requests that made it to the server.

Comment: Yes I know. I will give fiddler it a try. I just don't see why it will work sometimes though...

Comment: setting `cache:false` normally resolves the issue are you most certain that its still being cached?

Comment: I will set up fiddler tomorrow and report back :-)

Comment: I have added my solution bellow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was wrong about my assumption about caching of ajax requests. 
The real issue was caching of subsequent redirect to action requests that took place on the server (in response to the original ajax call).
The solution ended up being the following attribute.

```
[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None)]
```

It can be either applied at the controller level or the action level.

Answer (score 2):

The browser itself is simply not allowed/able to cache requests with distinct parameters, as added by `{cache:false}`.

It sounds like the caching is happening somewhere else in your chain, possibly in your web server/app.
Use firebug's net tab to check exactly what is being requested by the browser, and what the URLs are exactly, then take it from there.

Comment: I am using Asp.Net MVC 3 if that makes a difference

Comment: I have added my solution bellow